# Spark run multiple operations in parallel

Tags: multithreading, apache-spark

I have a Spark application picks a subset and do some operation on the subset. There is no dependency & interaction between each subset and its operation, so I tried to use multi threads to let them run parallel to improve performance. The code looks like below:

```
Dataset<Row> fullData = sparkSession.read().json("some_path");
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
List<Runnable> tasks = Lists.newArrayList();
for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
    final int x = i;
    tasks.add(() -> {
        Dataset<Row> subset_1 = fullData.filter(length(col("name")).equalTo(x));
        Dataset<Row> subset_2 = fullData.filter(length(col("name")).equalTo(x));
        Dataset<Row> result = subset_1.join(subset_2, ...);
        log.info("Res size is " + result.count()); // force Spark do the join operation
    });
}
CompletableFuture<?>[] futures = tasks.stream()
    .map(task -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(task, executor))
    .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new);
CompletableFuture.allOf(futures).join();
executor.shutdown();
```

From Spark job management UI, I noticed those 50 tasks are submitted in parallel, but the the processing is still in a blocking way, one task starts running until another task is complete. How can I make the multiple tasks run in parallel instead of one after another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how you control parallelism in Spark. It's all controlled declaratively via configuration.

Spark is a distributed computing framework and it's meant to be used in a distributed environment where each worker is ran single threaded. Usually tasks are scheduled using Yarn which has metadata of nodes and may will start multiple tasks on a single node (depending on memory and cpu constraints) but in separate jvms.

In `local` mode you can have multiple workers realized as separate threads, so if you  say `master("local[8]")` you will get 8 workers each running as a thread in a single jvm.

How are you running your application?

Comment: Thanks! I run my application by submitting a workflow through HUE UI. Can you add more details or share the link about how to config multiple workers?

Comment: Are you running on premise cluster? Or is it something managed like EMR? Or local run>?

Comment: it depends on many factors - number of nodes in your cluster, node types, amount of memory you declared for your spark application. Unfortunately it's a complicated topic. What helps is to open SPARK UI to see memory settings for your job, YARN UI to see memory configuration for your cluster. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hadoop-task-config.html shows default memory settings is Yarn depending on the node types used. Another topic the the parallelism of the data source - often it's 1 partition per file - if you don't have too many files try `DataFrame.repartition(n)`.

Comment: I tried another application with same pattern and the only difference is the join operation is lightweight, this application is able to run multiple tasks in parallel. Per my understanding, this depends on how much resource the task needs - if a task takes full resource of the node, then multiple tasks cannot be running in parallel.